# Android Image Rotate with ExifInterface not working

Tags: java, android, image-rotation

I'm using `ExifInterface` for rotate a image. image is placed as a child of a `ViewPager`. After I perform rotate, I checked the saved image and it changed its orientation. but my viewpager imageview still showing the previous orientation.

```
new AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Bitmap>(){
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        mRotateButtonImageView.setEnabled(false);
                        mCropButtonImageView.setEnabled(false);
                        mApplyFilterButtonImageView.setEnabled(false);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                        BitmapUtils.RotateBitmapWithExifInterface(CaptureActivity.captureOriginalImagePathsList.get(params[0]).getFinalImagePath().toString());
                        BitmapUtils.RotateBitmapWithExifInterface(CaptureActivity.captureOriginalImagePathsList.get(params[0]).getOriginalimagePath().toString());
                        BitmapUtils.RotateBitmapWithExifInterface(CaptureActivity.captureOriginalImagePathsList.get(params[0]).getmApplyFilterImagePath().toString());
                        return BitmapUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFile(CaptureActivity.captureOriginalImagePathsList.get(params[0]).getFinalImagePath().toString());
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap param) {
                        super.onPostExecute(param);
                        try {
                            mRotateButtonImageView.setEnabled(true);
                            mCropButtonImageView.setEnabled(true);
                            mApplyFilterButtonImageView.setEnabled(true);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            isRotating = false;
                            mCustomPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
                            iv.setImageBitmap(param);
                            //iv.setRotation(0);
                        }catch (Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }finally {
                            if(param != null)
                                param.recycle();
                                System.gc();
                                Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                        }

                    }
                }.execute(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```